# How to notify a processor once the activity is completed in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have to notify the processor once the activity is completed and along with a parameter. How to achieve this in apache Nifi

Comment: Could you please elaborate with the scenario, not able to clearly understand what you are trying to accomplish here!

Comment: I want to notify the processor once the loop of activity is fully completed. Currently i am using monitor activity for that. if monitor activity find the processor is inactive 15mins, It will trigger a message to next processor group to start

Comment: Did you try `wait-notify`? It is a kind of gate close-open mechanism implementation.